# Determining the value of the limit $ \displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p-h)}{h}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.  Determine the value of the following limit.  Prove that the limit is what you determined it to be: $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p-h)}{h}.$$  We have that

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p-h)}{h}& =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)+f(p)-f(p-h)}{h} \\ & =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(p)-f(p-h)}{h} \\ & =f'(p)-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(p-h)-f(p)}{h}. \end{aligned}$$

Comment: ..and then you just need to show that $ \frac{f(p) - f(p-h)}{h} \to f'(p)$ (which follows directly from the definition) to get the answer: $2f'(p)$

Comment: What is que question?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(p-h)-f(p)}h\stackrel{\text{subst.}\;h=-k}=-\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(p+k)-f(p)}k=-f'(p)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p-h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)+f(p)-f(p-h)}{h} $$
$$ =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(p)-f(p-h)}{h} $$
Let $z=-h$, then
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h}+\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(p+z)-f(p)}{z}= \frac{d}{dp}[f(p)]+\frac{d}{dp}[f(p)]= 2\frac{d}{dp}[f(p)] $$